# how can i use one file object in another class

Tags: java, file, bufferedreader

when i am using file object in another class that gives a error.
 there is any mechanism in java we can use object in another class.

```
class Abc {
    File file = new File("D:\\test.txt");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(alert_file));
}

class Def {
    File f_rename = new File("D:\\result.txt");
    if (file.renameTo(f_rename)) {
        System.out.println("file has been renamed");
    } else {
        System.out.println("file not renamed");
    }
}
```

Comment: your code won't compile

Comment: There are 2 fast approaches you can take, first one is instantiate the class which will contain the object, then you access it through the class object, the other one is making a static variable and saving the file there, which will be accessible at all times. It really depends on how you wanna do it.

Comment: [Passing Information to a Method or a Constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html)

Comment: That doesn't even come close to a valid Java program. Please get the basics right first (ie. put your logic in methods).

Comment: [java tutorial](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=passing+object+to+method+java&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=idq1VZW2LNaRuASsgoDgCQ#q=java+tutorial)

Answer (score 0):

The classes you write are only templates that you need to instantiate first. Here what you are doing is accessing variable of defined in the ABC class into class Def which is not allowed until you have object of class ABC in Def object.
Following code demonstrate how it can be done:

```
class MyClass{
     File file;
     public MyClass(){
        file=new File("somefile.txt");
     }
     //in some method you can write...
     public void someMethod(){
        SomeOtherClass soc=new SomeOtherClass(file);
        soc.someOtherMethod();
     }
} 

   class SomeOtherClass{
      File file; 
      public SomeOtherClass(File file){
        this.file=file;
      }
      public someOtherMethod(){
        //do whatever you want here with file object
      }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Which you written snippet of code is wrong,

class Abc {

public void checkFile(){

```
File file = new File("D:\\test.txt");
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(alert_file));
```

}

}

class Def {

public void checkFile()
{

```
File f_rename = new File("D:\\result.txt");
if (file.renameTo(f_rename)) {
    System.out.println("file has been renamed");
} else {
    System.out.println("file not renamed");
}
```

}

}

You can achieve in differ ways,

1. static variable.
2. instantiate obj & getter method.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Abc 
{
public static void main(String[] ars)
{
File file = new File("D:\\test.txt");
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(alert_file));
Def d=new Def();    
d.rename();
}
}

class Def {
public static void rename()
{
File f_rename = new File("D:\\result.txt");
if (Abc.file.renameTo(f_rename)) 
{
System.out.println("file has been renamed");
} 
else 
{
System.out.println("file not renamed");
}
}
}
```

Comment: this is simple solution.
put the class name before file object..
this is except able in java.